# Has some reason to MongoDB continues with write operation when i stop the service that writes?

Tags: mongodb, memory-leaks, real-time-data

I have some applications that read data in MongoDB and **only one that writes massively**(real time data). These applications and MongoDB was doing well a more than 3 months.

Today i saw that some applications was consuming a lot of memory and had bad performance, and i notice a big delay in the data that are insert in MongoDB.

So i report some facts:

1. **I stoped the service** that writes in MongoDB.
2. I noticed that even with the service turned off, the MongoDB still write data for more than 1 minute.

   2.1. I saw it when new data was write in the collection (have replicaset)

   2.2. In MongoCompass Perfomance tab, in hottest collection list, the writes opperations still with about 45% in the collection that service writes.
3. I executed some commands about concurrency/locks, and everything is fine, and had no clients writing
4. I executed a command to see memory of MongoDB and dont see everthing wrong or near the limits.
5. The MongoDB is "setuped" in a machine in EC2 with huge resources (i don't know whichs).

Any ideas to try troubleshooting that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use mongostat command from terminal to check what's happening in your database in real-time. Additionally, you can find the db.currentOp() from mongo shell to check which clients are currently writing to mongodb. Additionally, mongodb logs is good place to check if all of the intended connections from your application has stopped when you stop app services.